# How to make traffic from internal IP skip VPN on tomato router?

Tags: router, vpn, routing, openvpn, tomato

On my Tomato router, in the `VPN Client` section under `Advanced -> Custom Configuration`,  I need a command to cause all traffic **from** a **local ip** to skip the VPN.  `route my.static.local.ip 255.255.255.255 net_gateway`  does not work.

**what is the open vpn syntax to cause all traffic from a specific local ip to route through a specific gateway?**

thanks!

Comment: If I understand what you are asking to do, this is pretty hard, and will probably require policy based routing and iptables.  I'd be amazed if this can be done through a GUI.

Comment: what do you think im asking?

Comment: That you are wanting to handle traffic from 1 machine behind your network or the routed differently to others. This means source routing, which means more then 1 routing table and the complexities of policy based routing.